# (Scala) Creating a data structure for English words

Tags: scala, data-structures

I'm currently working on a problem that involves working with English words. I'm fairly new to functional programming and i want to write as good code as possible. It's a really simple question but i just wanna get this right!^^

How do i create a data structure for English words? I need it because if I ONLY used strings its bad - words can not have any numbers in it or any other inconsistent character - strings allow it.

I'm thinking of making a case class that overrides it's apply(or constructor - I come from OP background so i still mix these up) method that returns Either[String, EnglishWord] where Left would return me an error message - something like - "Found a number in your word". Am i thinking correctly? Any suggestions?

-Thank you so much!!

Cheers=)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27776500/5986907 ?

Comment: I'm not interested in compile time error in this case. I'm only asking for a data structure example that returns Either

Comment: Are you even sure that there are no English words that contain any digits? What's with "1st", "2nd", "[3D](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/3d)" and "[catch-22](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/catch-22)"?

Comment: Yeah, I'm wrong about that but you get the general idea ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should override the apply method, since you can't make the constructor return anything other than `EnglishWord`. If you want, you can make the constructor private so that people have to use the apply method.
2. You can use [`Try[EnglishWord]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html) instead of `Either[String, EnglishWord]`.
3. For this sort of thing (wrapping a type in another type for type safety), you may want a [value class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).
4. And, of course, make sure you allow corner-case words like "you're", "résumé", "façade", and, as Andrey pointed out, words with digits.

Here is an example:

```
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }

case class EnglishWord private(text: String) extends AnyVal

object EnglishWord {
  def apply(text: String): Try[EnglishWord] = {
    if (isValid(text)) {
      Success(new EnglishWord(text))
    } else {
      Failure(new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid word: " + text))
    }
  }

  def isValid(s: String): Boolean = ???
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! ^^